# É possível duas aplicações se comunicarem em uma rede Ad-Hoc?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Por exemplo, tenho um banco de dados em um PC e quero que uma aplicação localizada em outro PC acesse este banco.

É possível fazer isso via rede Ad-Hoc? Se sim, como?

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, mas o que seria uma "rede ad-hoc"?

Comment: É [isso aqui](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redes_ad_hoc)? Você não tem um roteador na sua rede?

Comment: Sim utluiz, é isso mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independentemente da topologia de sua rede, o acesso [direto] de um PC ao outro vai depender da sua capacidade de **endereçá-lo**, seja via endereço IP, DNS ou o que quer que seja (ex.: na sua rede ad-hoc os computadores têm **nomes**? É possível que usando esse nome, simplesmente, você consiga a conexão - da mesma forma que você já o faz através do sistema de arquivos).

Se todos os computadores estão "no mesmo nível", então deve ser possível acessar via IP. Use o `ipconfig` (windows) ou `ifconfig` (linux) no computador onde está o banco de dados, e procure pelo seu endereço IP (se houver mais de um, o que te interessa deve ser o da rede local, e deve estar no formato `192.168.X.Y` - onde `X` normalmente é `0` e `Y` é maior que `1`). Experimente colocar seu SGBD ouvindo nesse endereço, e no outro computador tente acessá-lo por esse endereço [mais a porta correta, se necessário].

Agora, se um computador está numa sub-rede e o que está querendo acessar está fora dela, então é necessário configurar um roteamento próprio ou talvez um proxy. Nesse caso, não tenho conhecimento suficiente para dar uma opinião.

Comment: Amigo, obrigado por responder. Testarei em casa e posto o resultado aqui :-)

Answer (score 5):

Se a aplicação funciona via rede, não importa qual a estrutura da mesma.

Se tem IP em ambos os hosts a aplicação deve funcionar (levando em conta que o firewall não está bloqueando a comunicação).

Answer (score 3):

Sim desde que que não precise de Internet ou de que um dos hosts atue como *gateway*...

Comment: Não espere velocidade alta ou comunicação full duplex, a comunicação wireless ad-hoc(na realidade o wirelles em geral) é similar a token ring..

Comment: Sim... Estou ciente de que é bastante lento.